# error loading /etc/profile (xinput property doesn't exist)

Tags: touchpad, 18.04, .profile

After upgrading from Xenial to Bionic, I now receive errors when logging into my desktop:

```
Error found when loading /etc/profile
Property 300 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
Property 299 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
Property 298 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
Property 300 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
Property 299 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
Property 298 doesn't exist, you must specify its type and format
```

I believe the culprit are the following lines I put both in `.profile` and `.xinputrc` to configure my touchpad:

```
xinput set-prop 11 298 1
xinput set-prop 11 299 1, 100
xinput set-prop 11 300 20.0 50000.0
```

However, if I do `source .profile`, then there's absolutely no problem, and my xinput settings are set correctly. It seems to only occur when these scripts are executed by /etc/profile. Has xinput not initialised my touchpad yet at that stage? And how can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you put the same lines in `/etc/profile` too ?

Comment: no; only in ~/.profile and ~/.xinputrc - I assume those are in turn loaded by /etc/profile ?